# How Can remove &nbsp; from html with jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I want remove `&nbsp;` from in a `div` with `jquery`. What should I do?

```
<div class="rating">
  <i data-alt="1"></i>
  &nbsp;
  <i data-alt="2"></i>
  &nbsp;
  <i data-alt="3"></i>
  &nbsp;
  <i data-alt="4"></i>
  &nbsp;
  <i data-alt="5"></i>
</div>
```

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you want it gone?

Comment: show code, not pictures

Answer (score 0):

you may replace the nbsp with blank string like these

```
$("div i").each(function() {
    var this = $(this);
    this.html(this.html().replace(/&nbsp;/g, ''));
});
```